# SDWebImage with JWT(JSON Web Token), how?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwt, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage(3.8.2) for downloading some images.
Here is the catch I got the URL's for the images in a JSON as normal.

However each URL (image URL) requires a JWT or it won't return the image.

On my other requests I set the JWT as such:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
//Set Token for request
[request setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"JWTToken"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

The SDWebImage code I'm using:

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/path/to/image"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

I took a look at SDWebImage methods but couldn't find a method that allows me to set a forHTTPHeaderField, how should I add the JWT Token to this request?

I saw this post: [SDWebImage and setting custom HTTP headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266462/sdwebimage-and-setting-custom-http-headers)

But I was wondering is there was a "Native" Method that allowed me to do so without potentially getting my code broken on future releases.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16708976/2164705

Comment: What's wrong with the solution in the linked question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2164705/ricardo-alves please make it an answer so I can mark it as correct.